# How can i prevent "STATEMENT: ..." logs written by system(?) everytime when my FDW calls elog() with LOG_SERVER_ONLY?

Tags: postgresql, logging

I'm making a FDW (Foreign Data Wrapper) in PostgreSQL for myself using C.
I want to write a log but not to display when some error occures.
so i thought elog & LOG_SERVER_ONLY is good way but
when my FDW calls elog() with LOG_SERVER_ONLY,
system(?) log "STATEMENT:  ..." appeares everytime.
How can i prevent it?

best regards.
yasoo7964

Answer (score 1):

[`errhidestmt`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/error-message-reporting.html) call should do the trick.

For example, [like here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_16_1/src/backend/utils/mmgr/mcxt.c#L741):

```
    ereport(LOG_SERVER_ONLY,
            (errhidestmt(true),
             errhidecontext(true),
             errmsg_internal("level: %d; %s: %s%s",
                             level, name, stats_string, truncated_ident)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Melkij !!